# if else array within an array

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I have defined the following function in my Wordpress site's functions.php file, it should give the option to turn comments on or off:

```
$wp_customize->add_section( 'display_comments', array(
    'title'     => 'Comments',
    'priority'  => 36,
) );

$wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_comments' );

$wp_customize->add_control( 'mytheme_comments', array(
    'label'   => 'Comments on or off',
    'section' => 'display_comments',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'default' => 'Off',
    'choices' => array(
        'value1' => 'On',
        'value2' => 'Off',
        ),
) );
```

I then have this in my single.php file, which is the page that shows an individual blog post:

```
<?php if (get_theme_mod ( 'mytheme_comments' == 'On' ) ) : ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php elseif (get_theme_mod ( 'mytheme_comments' == 'Off' ) ) : ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

The comments are off by default, but choosing 'on' from the dropdown, does not have any effect.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shuld change

```
if (get_theme_mod ( 'bistheme_comments' == 'On' ) )
```

To

```
if (get_theme_mod ( 'bistheme_comments') == 'On'  )
```

AND

```
elseif (get_theme_mod ( 'mytheme_comments' == 'Off' ) )
```

To

```
elseif (get_theme_mod ( 'mytheme_comments') == 'Off'  )
```

Better way to rewrite your code

```
$var = get_theme_mod('mytheme_comments');
if ($var == 'On') {
    comments_template();
} else if ($var == 'Off') {
    // Var is Off
} else {
    // Var was not set 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried making the changes, but for some reason it still is not registering a change.

Comment: @user18577 can i see your updated code .. add the full code to pastbin

Comment: You code looks fine .... what exactly is the error ???? what do you want to register

Comment: I've figured it out, sorry - in single.php it should be 'value1' and 'value2' not 'on' and 'off'! Thanks!